# What is wrong with my pattern matching?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Files in my directory

```
262_V01_C00_R000_TEx_BL_2048H.dat  262_V01_C02_R000_THx_BL_2048H.dat
262_V01_C01_R000_TEy_BL_2048H.dat  262_V01_C03_R000_THy_BL_2048H.dat
```

My script

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.dat;
do
    if [ "$i" == "$TEx" ];then
        file1= "$i"
    fi
    if [ "$i" == "$TEy" ];then
        file2= "$i"
    fi
done

echo file1
echo file2
```

I got

```
file1
file2
```

My aim was

```
file1=262_V01_C00_R000_TEx_BL_2048H.dat
file2=262_V01_C00_R000_TEy_BL_2048H.dat
```

Comment: This is the same error you made in your previous question, which was corrected in the answer you accepted.

Comment: In both questions, he is asking why the name of a variable is output instead of its value. Granted, this question has the additional error of putting whitespace after the `=`, but I have to wonder if he even read the answer to his previous question.

Comment: @chepner I admit my mistake,yes I have read the answer.But here it is regex issue for sure!

Comment: There is an issue with your attempt at pattern matching, but it's obscured by your failure to fix the error from your previous question.

Comment: @Richard Rublev, Start by using [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) before posting.

Comment: @user3439894 Ok,will try for sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

- `[[ "$i" =~ TEx ]]` instead of `[ "$i" == "$TEx" ]`.
- `file1=$i`, without spaces around `=`. Also, the double quotes are not necessary.
- `echo file1=$file1` not just `echo file1`.